# Counting how many times in a row the result of a sum is positive (or negative)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**First Part**

> I have a dataframe with finance data (33023 rows, here the link to the
>   data: https://mab.to/Ssy3TelRs); df.open is the price of the title and
>   df.close is the closing price.
>
> I have been trying to see how many times in a row the title closed
>   with a gain and with a lost.
>
> The result that I'm looking for should tell me that the title was
>   positive 2 days in a row x times, 3 days in a row y times, 4 days in a
>   row z times and so forth.
>
> I have started with a for:
>
> ```
> for x in range(1,df.close.count()):   y = df.close[x]-df.open[x]
> ```
>
> and then unsuccessful series of if statements...
>
> Thank you for your help.
>
> CronosVirus00
>
> EDITS:
>
> ```
> >>> df.head(7)
>        data  ora     open      max      min    close  Unnamed: 6
> 0  20160801    0  1.11781  1.11781  1.11772  1.11773           0
> 1  20160801  100  1.11774  1.11779  1.11773  1.11777           0
> 2  20160801  200  1.11779  1.11800  1.11779  1.11795           0
> 3  20160801  300  1.11794  1.11801  1.11771  1.11771           0
> 4  20160801  400  1.11766  1.11772  1.11763  1.11772           0
> 5  20160801  500  1.11774  1.11798  1.11774  1.11796           0
> 6  20160801  600  1.11796  1.11796  1.11783  1.11783           0
> ```
>
> Ifs:
>
> ```
> for x in range(1,df.close.count()):   y = df.close[x]-df.open[x]  if y > 0 :      green += 1      y = df.close[x+1] - df.close[x+1]
>   twotimes += 1       if y > 0 :          green += 1          y = df.close[x+2] -
> ```
>
> df.close[x+2]             threetimes += 1             if y > 0 :
>                 green += 1          y = df.close[x+3] - df.close[x+3]           fourtimes += 1
>
> FINAL SOLUTION
>
> Thank you all! And the end I did this:
>
> ```
> df['test'] = df.close - df.open >0
> green = df.test #days that it was positive
>
> def gg(z):
>     tot =green.count()
>     giorni = range (1,z+1) # days in a row i wanna check
>     for x in giorni:
>         y = (green.rolling(x).sum()>x-1).sum()
>         print(x," ",y, " ", round((y/tot)*100,1),"%")
>
> gg(5)
> 1   14850   45.0 %
> 2   6647   20.1 %
> 3   2980   9.0 %
> 4   1346   4.1 %
> 5   607   1.8 %
> ```

Comment: Please include your unsuccessful if-statements.  Also, python is indentation depended, so you please ensure your code is formatted here the *exact* same way it is in your code.

Comment: Do you want  the number of days that have at least n positive days in a row before and itself included, or the number of periods with at least `n` positive days in a row?

Comment: Could you also provide a desired data set / DF?

Comment: Link Available in edit

Comment: @CronosVirus00, is [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39516000/5741205) what you want or did i misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly you can do it this way:

```
In [76]: df.groupby((df.close.diff() < 0).cumsum()).cumcount()
Out[76]:
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    1
5    2
6    0
7    0
dtype: int64
```

> The result that I'm looking for should tell me that the title was
>   positive 2 days in a row x times, 3 days in a row y times, 4 days in a
>   row z times and so forth.

```
In [114]: df.groupby((df.close.diff() < 0).cumsum()).cumcount().value_counts().to_frame('count')
Out[114]:
   count
0      4
2      2
1      2
```

Data set:

```
In [78]: df
Out[78]:
       data  ora     open      max      min    close
0  20160801    0  1.11781  1.11781  1.11772  1.11773
1  20160801  100  1.11774  1.11779  1.11773  1.11777
2  20160801  200  1.11779  1.11800  1.11779  1.11795
3  20160801  300  1.11794  1.11801  1.11771  1.11771
4  20160801  400  1.11766  1.11772  1.11763  1.11772
5  20160801  500  1.11774  1.11798  1.11774  1.11796
6  20160801  600  1.11796  1.11796  1.11783  1.11783
7  20160801  700  1.11783  1.11799  1.11783  1.11780

In [80]: df.close.diff()
Out[80]:
0        NaN
1    0.00004
2    0.00018
3   -0.00024
4    0.00001
5    0.00024
6   -0.00013
7   -0.00003
Name: close, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want to do is:

- compute the difference of two series (open & close), eg `diff = df.open - df.close`
- apply a condition to the result to get a boolean series `diff > 0`
- pass the resulting boolean series to the DataFrame to get a subset of the DataFrame where the condition is true `df[diff > 0]`
- Find all contiguous subsequences by applying a column wise function to identify and count

I need to board a plane, but I will provide a sample of what the last step looks like when I can.

Comment: Your first 3 points are spot on! Now I need to figure out how to do your 4th suggestion. Keep you updated

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you want the number of days that have at least `n` positive days in a row before and itself included.

Similarly to what @Thang suggested, you can use [rolling](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 2), columns=["open", "close"])
# This just sets up random test data, for example:
#       open     close
# 0  0.997986  0.594789
# 1  0.052712  0.401275
# 2  0.895179  0.842259
# 3  0.747268  0.919169
# 4  0.113408  0.253440
# 5  0.199062  0.399003
# 6  0.436424  0.514781
# 7  0.180154  0.235816
# 8  0.750042  0.558278
# 9  0.840404  0.139869

positiveDays = df["close"]-df["open"] > 0
# This will give you a series that is True for positive days:
# 0    False
# 1     True
# 2    False
# 3     True
# 4     True
# 5     True
# 6     True
# 7     True
# 8    False
# 9    False
# dtype: bool

daysToCheck = 3
positiveDays.rolling(daysToCheck).sum()>daysToCheck-1
```

This will now give you a series, indicating for every day, whether it has been positive for `daysToCheck` number of days in a row:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool
```

Now you can use `(positiveDays.rolling(daysToCheck).sum()>daysToCheck-1).sum()` to get the number of days (in the example `3`) that obey this, which is what you want, as far as I understand.

Comment: I am updating now pandas because the rolling is available from the 0.18 version (I had the 0.17). I will let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,2), columns = ['open','close'])

test['gain?'] = (test['open']-test['close'] < 0)
test['cumulative'] = 0

for i in test.index[1:]:
    if test['gain?'][i]:
        test['cumulative'][i] = test['cumulative'][i-1] + 1
        test['cumulative'][i-1] = 0

results = test['cumulative'].value_counts()
```

Ignore the '0' row in the results. It can be modified without too much trouble if you want to e.g count both days in a run-of-two as runs-of-one as well.

Edit: without the warnings -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,2), columns = ['open','close'])
test['gain?'] = (test['open']-test['close'] < 0)
test['cumulative'] = 0

for i in test.index[1:]:
    if test['gain?'][i]:
        test.loc[i,'cumulative'] = test.loc[i-1,'cumulative'] + 1
        test.loc[i-1,'cumulative'] = 0

results = test['cumulative'].value_counts()
```

Comment: It gives me this error:
test['cumulative'][i] = test['cumulative'][i-1] + 1
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Comment: I don't /think/ the warning makes a difference? But I've edited to remove it anyways.